# Does Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) utilise the integrated GPU in Intel CPUs?

Tags: vectorization, gpgpu, intel-mkl

I understand Intel MKL will interrogate the CPU for existence of extended instruction sets such as the various SSE to SSE 4.2, AVX, AVX2, etc. in order to select the best subroutine available for a given CPU.

Now that many of Intel's consumer CPUs contain an integrated GPU I was wondering if the Intel MKL utilises them?

Answer (score 2):

In Intel MKL system requirements page https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2017-system-requirements does not include any information about GPUs being supported. There is also no mention about it in the documentation.

The only accelerator they support is Xeon Phi. Therefore, there is no support for GPUs from MKL as of now.